# iOS Facebook Login in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to implement the exact same code mentioned in the docs, so when I get the granted permissions from the user in the below way

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(
        permissions: [.email , .publicProfile],
        viewController: self
    ) { result in
        self.loginManagerDidComplete(result)
    }
```

how can I decode the **publicProfile** to get all the inside information..

I know that there are other ways to get these details, but can I get a solution only with this code.

Can we get the details from the below code

```
switch result {
    case .cancelled:
        print("User cancelled login.")

    case .failed(let error):
        print("Login failed with error \(error)")

    case .success(let grantedPermissions, _, _):
        print("Login succeeded with granted permissions: \(grantedPermissions)")
        print(grantedPermissions.map { $0.name },"test")
        for perm in grantedPermissions {
            print(perm.name,perm.hashValue)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your completion handler for your login permissions, make a graph request to obtain the profile information. Your login function only asks for permissions and the subsequent call will return the information you require.

```
switch result {
    case .failed(let error):
           print(error)
    case .cancelled:
           print("Cancelled")
    case .success(_,_,_):
           let params = ["fields" : "id, email, first_name, last_name"]
           let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: params)
           graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { ( connection, result, error) in
                if let error = error as Error? {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

                if let result = result as? [String: String],
                    let id = result["id"],
                    let firstName = result["first_name"],
                    let lastName = result["last_name"],
                    let email = result["email"]
                })
}
```

Comment: can we get it from the above code in the edited question?? The answer which you gave I've already implemented..but trying to get from the above code..is that possible??

Comment: No, you need to make the Graph Request. As mentioned in my answer, the result from grantedPermissions is just that, the permissions you've been granted. You need to be approved for those on login, before you can then go on to request the details from Graph. You will also find this information in the Swift FBSDK docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login